# How do I interpret these instructions?

Tags: git, github

Please correct me if my interpretation is wrong, i am a noob at github

My boss told me this

1. Make a local branch in your PC of this repo and execute pull in order to install a local copy of the application in your local machine.
2. Create multipoint branch in your PC and execute pull from this repo.
3. You need to get these 3 files: file1.js file2.js file3.js

I interepreted this as: (please correct me if im mistaken)

1. so I fork the repo and clone it on my pc

   git clone _my_repo_url_

   git remote add upstream _original_repo_url_

   git pull upstream

trying that gave me this error

You asked to pull from the remote 'upstream', but did not specify a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.

1. create a new branch called 'multipoint' (--? what is a 'multipoint branch' anyway)

   git checkout -b multipoint

so i have to pull again right?

```
git fetch upstream
```

1. i totally have no idea :(

Please help me, git and github are not really my forte

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your description but you may want to do something like this:

1. Fork the repo on the github web-site so that you have a repo where you have read-write access..
2. Clone your fork to your local machine (github will present the url to clone)
   git clone
3. Add a new remote to the original repo (the repo you will likely only have read access to)
   git remote add upstream
4. git checkout -b multipoint  (to get a feature branch)
5. Hack away

At a later point in time you can bring down new commits from the original repo using:

1. git checkout master
2. git pull upstream master

And finally (if you want) to move your commits so that they are based on the new master:

1. git checkout multipoint
2. git rebase master

Comment: you sir deserves an upvote but i cant yet with my account. i just have a few q's about it as even i am not sure if i should follow it word per word. (1) i already have r/w access on the repo, base from the instructions do i have to really fork it? (2) will 'git pull upstream master' update other branches as well? TYVM!

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit of a guess based on your boss' limited description, but this looks likely:

```
$ git clone <the repo> <my-working-directory>
```

With the clone you automatically have a remote defined that is called 'origin' and a 'master' branch that is tracking origin/master.

```
$ cd <my-working-directory>
$ git remote show origin
```

The result of show ought to indicate what branches exist on 'origin' - hopefully you see 'multipoint.

```
$ git branch --track multipoint origin/multipoint
```

You've now created a local 'multipoint' branch that is tracking origin/multipoint.

```
$ git checkout multipoint
```

At this point, your three files should be present!

Comment: thank you sir :) so does that mean that pushing changes to multipoint affects origin/multipoint only?

Comment: Yes.  Do 'git remote show origin' it will say that multipoint is pushing and pulling from origin/multipoint.